# I can't access a char as a string

Tags: c, string, char, strcmp

I have the following bit of code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char values[] = {"abcde"};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", strcmp(&values[0], argv[1]));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile and launch this way:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ ./main a
98
```

The result of `strcmp`is 98, so the values are not the same. When I replace `&values[0]` by `"a"` in the code, I see that they are the same (`strcmp` output is equal to 0).

So is there a way to access `values[0]` as a string ? I guess that I need to somehow specify `\0` at the end in order for the char to be used as a string, but I can't find a way.

Comment: `{"abcde"};` <- Why the braces?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks like a XY problem.

Comment: I do not understand. `So is there a way to access values[0] as a string ?` You are accessing it as a string (for me). What does it mean to "access something as a string"? Do you want to _compare only the initial portion of the string_? Ie. you explained what is happening. Please explain what you _want_ to happen instead.

Comment: @klutt I am using the braces to define an array. But I'm not sure this is how to do it in an idiomatic way

Comment: @RicoRico I'm trying to build a hash bruteforce program, so I need to test every letter in the alphabet individually

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry for the lack of explanation. My final goal is to be able to find a way to make values[0] equal to "a". The solution Aplet123 provided is working for my case, maybe it will help understand what I wanted to do !

Comment: @HugoBlanc Well, the braces are not needed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `values[0]` is not followed by a null-byte, so you end up comparing `"abcde"` with `"a"`, which is not what you want. You can instead allocate a two char array that has a nullbyte:

```c
char mystr[2] = {values[0]}; // rest of the array is zeroed (null bytes)
printf("%d\n", strcmp(mystr, argv[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Without copying `values[0]` (as [Aplet123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65012903/2422776) suggests) or modifying `values`, you could use `strncmp` to specify that only up to one character should be compared:

```c
printf("%d\n", strncmp(values, argv[1], 1));
```